# How can I send push notification to selected Users iphone?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have selected 5 users from my mobile contacts and uploaded them to server.

Now which use among five installs this application, has to fill phone number which also be saved on server.

If I press a button "Send Notification" , a push notification will be send to those five which I saved.

Is it possible to send PUSH NOTIFICATION to particular persons to whom I have added in my list and on server?

If yes, then how?

Comment: What software are you using on the server to handle sending the push notifications?

Comment: I am unaware of server, I am handling client side, but they might use PHP and Urban Airship, or native Apple Notification System,

Comment: short answer: yes. longer answer: read the docs, this requires a client and server implementation. BaaS vendors such as Urban Airship can provide with a backend (server).

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise reading:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW1

If you're using a third-party system for providing the push notifications using Urban Airship for example, then their system will be set up to discriminate against particular UDIDs. Its certainly possible; implementation details will vary between different vendors.

Comment: you simply wana say that it will send to all the devices which are registered?

Comment: All vendors will be able to send to particular device UDIDs. How you do that depends on which vendor you're using (or even if you wrote the server yourself). For example, in Urban Airship, you can tag particular users with a given tag, and then use that tag to broadcast to only users with that tag.